# Is there a way to package add-ins so that users only have to click one to use all macros within it?

Tags: vba, excel-addins

I've got a dozen macros that have 90% similar code. I've created 4 sets of VBA in an add-in file so that I don't have to revise a dozen different places any time a change needs to be made. The plan is to end up with:

```
specific code
universal code A
specific code
universal code B
```

The users are not particularly tech-savvy so I want to make the distribution as painless and idiot-proof as possible.

Also, the add-ins don't have to be visible--no one is going to run them on their own, they're just going to be embedded and called upon from other macros.

I've looked around online and the closest thing I've found is this [How to combine multiple VBA macros into one add-in file for Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384135/how-to-combine-multiple-vba-macros-into-one-add-in-file-for-excel)

It still looks like this is geared more towards having multiple buttons, which I really don't need (or want...I don't actually want ANY buttons)

Not really sure what kind of code I could show to help with this problem, since I don't know if this is even possible to do.

Answer (score 0):

Once you save the XLAM file you just have to click on Excel Add-ins under the Developer tab, browse to the folder where it is stored, and open. It will then appear as an add-in package that you can click on.